# Why is setting device read-only flag dangerous in hdparm?

Tags: hdparm

In the `hdparm` man page the `-r` option is not mentioned as being dangerous but in the help list of options shown with `-h` it says:

`-r   Get/set device readonly flag (DANGEROUS to set)`

Is there a reason why it may be dangerous to set a read-only flag for a disk drive? Or could this possibly be a typo since every other option in the help list has an associated warning in the man page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same option is also used to clear the readonly flag, converting the drive from read only to read/write.

For drives that really don't support read/write operations, the OS will attempt to handle requests by programs to write the drive, and the drive will probably respond with errors; but, many read only drives are not tested heavily for handling write commands.  There is a chance that your drive will not respond with high quality errors, leading to the operating system getting a different understanding of the hardware state than really exists within the machine.

As the operating system gets a "different" understanding of the hardware than the hardware state, new commands are now working on a misunderstanding of the true hardware state.  The operating system can recover (in some cases) bad hardware configurations, but only if it understands the bad configurations exist.  If it understands that the hardware is working well, it won't attempt to recover hardware, and may issue more commands to a device that's already in a bad state.

Why isn't hardware fully tested for every operation?  For some hardware it makes no sense to fully test the hardware.  For example, few people would really get mad if you didn't test that you had the right error code for a write to a CDROM, because many of these people would believe that the operating system would never write to a CDROM (as it can't change the plastic disk).

Why does hardware sometimes lock up when given bad commands?  It has to do with a lot of hardware having the programs that handle commands being implemented in a way that has to use very few resources and run very quickly.  This means that a 100% complete handling of every state is often not programmed into the hardware controller, because commands that should never be issued after other commands are never seen in a correctly functioning operating system.  Also, in some cases a full ability to respond to all commands means slower hardware controllers, or hardware controllers that require larger / more powerful chips to store / process the commands.

I hope these worries give you some idea behind the "this is dangerous" comment.  While setting read / write to "read only" is generally less dangerous (unless you have a non-complete write that is pending) setting it "read / write" can be really bad in some circumstances.